# Setting Camera Rotation

Tags: opengl

How do I set a camera rotation given a rotational matrix M (M is a 4 by 4 matrix)

Answer (score 0):

[`glLoadMatrix()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml):

> Description
>
> glLoadMatrix replaces the current matrix with the one whose elements are specified by m.  The current matrix is the projection matrix, modelview matrix, or texture matrix, depending on the current matrix mode (see glMatrixMode).